# What's so special about multi-linearity?

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

When deriving determinants from first principals, we start with multi-linearity and the alternating property. Coupling this with the fact that the determinant of the identity matrix must be $1$, we get the Leibniz formula for determinants. All of this is spelled out [in this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9IswLDsEWFk). It also motivates the two properties (multi-linearity and the alternating property) geometrically.

I'm wondering if there is a purely algebraic motivation for why multi-linearity and the alternating property are indispensable? Does it have something to do with the fact that we're talking about quantifying the effects of linear maps?

Comment: Indispensable for what?

Comment: This property seems to be the starting point for all proofs relating to determinants.

Comment: You are reversing the order of development. People got Leibniz’ formula first from elimination of variables from system of linear equations. Then they observed that the determinant is multilinear and alternating in the matrix rows/columns. Then Weierstrass and some others tried to use multilinearity and alternation as first principles to derive the existence of determinant. The usefulness of multilinearity wasn’t foreseen.

Comment: @user1551 That's exactly what I do at the beginning of the video in the 2x2 case for motivation. I cite Curtis in the references because it inspired that in the video. He took the approach from the classic older book by Schrier and Sperner, as he notes. I added the "done right" in the title to poke fun at Sheldon Axler. :)

Comment: Others of us allude to Cavalieri's principle as a guiding light in the geometric meaning of determinant. You'll find this also in Section 3 of Chapter 5 of the second edition of Shifrin and Adams, *Linear Algebra: A Geometric Approach*. :) But since hardly anyone will teach that section, we did use the standard definition, I confess.

Comment: @user1551 Thanks for your comments. Yes, as you note I switch over to the Weierstrass properties for $n$ dimensions after showing how they fall out in low dimension, where you can easily see the geometry. One great thing about determinants is the different choices that can be made in exposition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The determinant has many different properties that uniquely determine it so it can be developed starting from multiple different combinations of those properties. Alternating + multilinear is a common one, as is the oriented volume stuff over $\mathbb{R}$.

However, I'd argue that neither of these is a good place to motivate the determinant, and neither of them is the historical motivation. Alternating + multilinear leads to elegant proofs but it leads to exactly your question: why study a function satisfying these properties? Oriented volumes are a good thing to know about but they only motivate the determinant over $\mathbb{R}$, whereas the determinant in fact makes sense and is very useful over any field, and even over any commutative ring. In fact hardly any treatments of the determinant really emphasize one of its most important features in practice: it is a *polynomial*, with *integer* coefficients.

The historical motivation of the determinant is the simplest possible one you could imagine, and the one students are first exposed to: solving systems of linear equations. It is just the function you are forced to write down when you solve systems of $n$ linear equations in $n$ variables. It is called the determinant because it *determines* when such systems have unique solutions.

So, along these lines, here is a purely algebraic definition of the determinant that does not mention the concept of an alternating or multilinear map at all, and defines the determinant as a *polynomial* (so, over every commutative ring simultaneously): start with an $n \times n$ matrix whose entries are *indeterminates*

$$X = \left[ \begin{array}{cccc} x_{11} & x_{12} & \dots & x_{1n} \\ x_{21} & x_{22} & \dots & x_{2n} \\
 \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
 x_{n1} & x_{n2} & \dots & x_{nn} \end{array} \right].$$

This is the *universal matrix.* Now suppose I asked you to try to invert this matrix. A systematic way to do this would be row reduction. In terms of solving systems of linear equations this corresponds to trying to eliminate variables. If you row reduce the above matrix while repeatedly assuming that every expression you need to be invertible is actually invertible (so, precisely, working over the fraction field of $\mathbb{Z}[x_{ij}]$), you will eventually write down the [LU decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LU_decomposition) of the universal matrix, which you can use to write down the inverse.

What you will find is that the inverse has the property that every entry is a rational function of the $x_{ij}$, and moreover all the denominators are the *same* polynomial. This polynomial is the determinant (this is [Cramer's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer%27s_rule)). So, with this approach to the determinant we make the decision that the real defining feature of the determinant is that it is a polynomial in the entries of a matrix $X$ that is invertible iff $X$ is invertible, and whose inverse can be used to write down $X^{-1}$ explicitly. (Over a field we could also say "that vanishes iff $X$ is non-invertible." Also, this only tells us the determinant up to a sign but we can fix the sign by requiring that $\det(I) = 1$.)

This definition is a little awkward to start with because it's a little hard to prove things about (we need to prove Cramer's rule even to get started), which is probably why it's not a popular choice of starting point. But in my opinion this is the best-motivated definition from first principles by far. We get to alternating + multilinear from here by proving that $\det(XY) = \det(X) \det(Y)$, which you can see (up to a sign) from the fact that if you take $X$ and $Y$ to both have indeterminate entries $x_{ij}$ and $y_{ij}$ then $(XY)^{-1} = Y^{-1} X^{-1}$ has entries consisting of a bunch of rational functions with denominator $\det(Y) \det(X)$. From multiplicativity it follows that the determinant has the usual behavior you expect with respect to row and column operations and it's not hard to prove that it's alternating + multilinear from here (over, and I want to keep emphasizing this, every commutative ring simultaneously).

Comment: Thank. What do you mean by invertible polynomial? Over the reals, it seems that only the constant polynomial admits this property.

Comment: @Rohit: we aren't working over the polynomial ring here, we're working as I said over its fraction field, of rational functions. So we just formally invert all necessary polynomials. The polynomials you need to invert to write down the LU decomposition turn out to be exactly the principal minors, but in the end you get a formula for the inverse that requires you to invert only a single polynomial, the determinant.

Comment: Readers who like this approach to the determinant might also like Satake's treatment in his book *Linear Algebra* (1975), in which the determinant is defined as a polynomial in $n^2$ indeterminates $x_{ij}$ -- but starting with the Leibniz expansion rather than inversion.

Comment: Mac Duffee’s *Vectors and Matrices* (1943) also defines the determinant as a polynomial of the least possible degree in $n^2$ indeterminates of a generic matrix such that it is multiplicative (i.e., $\det(AB)=\det(A)\det(B)$), but he had to prove Weierstrass‘ axioms in order to obtain an explicit expression for the determinant.