# Why can't multi-linearity be motivated for linear maps?

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

The Leibniz formula for determinants starts with multi-linearity and the alternating property and builds from there. I asked a question about why we should start with multi-linearity: [What's so special about multi-linearity?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4782362/whats-so-special-about-multi-linearity). And the response (which had an excellent alternate motivation for the determinant which I wasn't aware of) seemed to be that there is indeed no good reason.

The thing that keeps bothering me is that we are talking about linear maps here. And the determinant is really a property of the linear map. And given the definitions of linearity in the context of linear maps and the multi-linearity of determinants look exactly the same, I would assume a statement like this exists - "because the determinant is a property of linear maps, it clearly must satisfy the property of multi-linearity because _____". Is there no way to fill in the blank?

Comment: The response there did not say "there is no good reason", but rather that there are also *other* reasons. And it indicates that approaching the determinant as a universal polynomial might not be easy to work with in class. In your post above, you are missing an *essential* aspect of determinants: they are not just multilinear, but also alternating.  Nobody is saying either properties is natural, but *together* they essentially characterize the determinant. Don't omit either one.Since they characterize determinants, that is why they are used together. It takes getting used to, sure.

Comment: Volume forms are multilinear. For example just looking at the usual volume of a rectangular prism with formula $V=lwh$ we see that it's multilinear in the length, width and height. Thus they arise naturally when studying the most basic geometric properties of vectors.

Comment: Yes, but I'm wondering if it's possible to motivate without geometry. Just starting with the fact that we are quantifying the effect of linear maps.